Unable to create Athena table from JSON file
I have a JSON file like below stored in S3:
{
  "workflow": {
    "req": {
      "ap": {
        "id": 799330,
        "reqname": "Mimi",
        "manual": true,
        "portappid": "DTV2207241418NT00",
        "status": null,
        "createdBy": "DealerTrack_v3",
        "createdOn": "2024-07-22T12:19:39.017",
        "requestDate": "2001-02-13T19:00:00",
        "appno": "DTV2207241418NT00",
        "abc": null,
        "type1": "retail"
      }
    }
  }
}

When I am creating the crawler to crawl this JSON file, the crawler is getting executed successfully but when i am querying the table its giving blank result. Not sure where its going wrong.
DDL created by crawler is as below:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `new1_json`(
  `workflow` struct<req:struct<ap:struct<id:int,reqname:string,manual:boolean,portappid:string,status:string,createdby:string,createdon:string,requestdate:string,appno:string,abc:string,type1:string>>> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'paths'='workflow') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://files_bucket/raw/file1/new1.json'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='crawler1', 
  'averageRecordSize'='456', 
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='1', 
  'sizeKey'='456', 
  'typeOfData'='file')

When I am querying the table, its giving below output:


How are you querying the table -- just using select * from table? Please Edit your Question and include the DDL that the crawler generated to define the table.

I have added DDL generated by crawler.. thanks!

yes i am using select * from table

It looks like your location is pointing directly to the file; Athena requires location to point to the prefix to list files under. I think you will start seeing data if you change the location clause like so:
LOCATION
    's3://files_bucket/raw/file1/'

